# Typing /**/ in PHP files

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I use `/**/` as personal marker for code bits that need to be addressed before committing. As soon as I type this:

```
/**
```

… the editor thinks I want a docblock and triggers auto-completion:

```
/**| */
```

… where `|` is the cursor. Thus when I type the final slash what I finally get:

```
/**/| */
```

This happens with several PHP extensions installed (including PHP DocBlocker and Felix Becker's PHP Extension Pack) and also with `--disable-extensions` so it must be triggered by builtin auto-completion.

Is there a setting I can tweak to prevent this?

Comment: The convention is to type `//TODO some comment what to do`
then most enviroments will put it automatically in a TODO list too where you can click to jump to that code block

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to change your coding style - most people use /** TODO: whatever */.

Comment: `/**` is conventionally used in IDEs for documentation comments. See phpdoc.org

Comment: @Tschallacka That's precisely the reason to use a different marker. I want to ensure that I detect my unfinished code at first glimpse so I do not commit it to version control. I don't want to browse all project-wide todo's to tell out mine every time.

Comment: @Barmar Of course, `/**/` is not a valid docblock because, well, it's empty :) Other editors I've used would only auto-complete when I type a space, tab or enter afterwards.

Comment: Yeah, PhpStorm works like that. I guess VSCode is a little more aggressive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell that's how the feature works and there's no [setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) to tweak or even disable it. Thus I've opened a feature request: [#51047 autoClosingPairs are too aggressive](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/51047#issuecomment-394167977). (`autoClosingPairs` is involved because it's handled the same way as brackets.)

As workaround, I've created a custom code snippet:

```
"/**/": {
    "prefix": "/**/",
    "body": "/**/",
    "description": "Workaround to be able to type /**/"
}
```

I only need to be careful and type <kbd>/</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>/</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd>) but once you get used to it it's actually a time saver.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
// TODO some_description_of_what_to_do
```

or

```
/** TODO some_description_of_what_to_do */
```

This is a common convention to mark something.

Yo can omit description part and just mark it as

```
// TODO* 
// or 
/** TODO */
```

Most IDE (PhpStorm for sure) will highlight such comment and you'll be able to see it even better. Also there is an option when you commit via IDE to check for TODO marks before commit.

Just try it and you'll notice how handy it is ;)

P.S.: In case you are using Visual Studio Code https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wayou.vscode-todo-highlight

Comment: The codebase I'm currently working on has 102 of such markers and it's a small project. Injecting my temporary markers into those feels like a crazy idea...